# pip install in order from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, statsmodels, egg

I want to install statemodel so i am running

```
sudo pip install --upgrade -r /srv/requirements.txt
```

contain of requirements.txt

```
cat requirements.txt
numpy==1.9.0
scipy==0.14.0
patsy==0.3.0
pandas==0.13.0
statsmodels==0.5.0
```

but it looks like pip is not installing packages listed in requirements.txt in order
because I am getting dependency error like "statsmodels required scipy"

Is there any way to make pip to install packages in the order they have listed in requirements.txt ?

Comment: Please search the scipy and statsmodels issue list before you report this as a bug. This is fixed in master and a release will be forthcoming very shortly.

Answer (score 3):

You could install using the `pip` module

```
import pip
with open("requirements.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # call pip's main function with each requirement
        pip.main(['install','-U', line])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /srv/requeriments.txt | xargs pip install --upgrade -r
```

Comment: This is not work unfortunately